# Augmented Reality samples on android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am trying to find Github projects of Augmented Reality,

***Where I can view the picture of a wall and change the color of it in real time.***

**`Ex`**: if the wall color is white , I can select a color from a palette of colors

- Are there any sample projects on this
- How to search tutorials to learn this

Answer (score 0):

GDNative based OpenVR plugin for Godot

https://github.com/BastiaanOlij/godot_openvr